# Linq to entity navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need to get the 3rd level entities using navigation properties.

table1
table2
table3
table4
table5
Table 1 relates to table2 and table 2 relates to table 3,4,5 with foreign key relation ships.
I want to pull the data from table 3,4,5 based on the table1 fields. I tried to use the include method but unable to find the method. If you can give the sample code that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the include method in `System.Data.Objects`. Include should work with the `.Include("Table1.PropertyNameTable2.PropertyNameTable3.PropertyNameTable4");` notation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx

Comment: Could not find the .Include method.

Comment: Try: using System.Data.Objects;